# Is there any way to run PowerPC applications on Mountain Lion (Not installing-just opening from a CD)

Tags: macos, powerpc

I have old software (will run from a CD) in both a Mac OSX (10.5.8) and Mac OS9 version which I would like to run on Mt Lion, MacBook Pro 2012. A very similar question has been asked and answered here, my question differs in that the software is on a CD and is run from the CD, local installation is not required. Does this change the answers that can be found at link below, addressing installation of the old software on the same machine running Mt Lion. Thanks for any feed back.

See [Is there a way to install and use PowerPC applications on Intel Macs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44436/is-there-a-way-to-install-and-use-powerpc-applications-on-intel-macs)

Comment: This isn't really a different question from the one you've linked to; the inability of ML to run PowerPC applications has nothing to do with where the applications are stored - their binary representation is what's incompatible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to install and use PowerPC applications on Intel Macs?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44436/is-there-a-way-to-install-and-use-powerpc-applications-on-intel-macs)

Comment: There is no difference whether your application runs from the CD or otherwise. The thread linked is your best resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: No.
Long answer: Yes, you can. You can run Snow Leopard in a VM (virtual machine) on your computer.

There are paid solutions like [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) and [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com), but a great free solution is VirtualBox. There is a fabulous guide on how to install Mac OS X Snow Leopard [here](http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows)

Note: You will need a version of Mac OS X Snow Leopard to install on the Virtual Machine. If you don't own it, Apple is still selling it [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard).

Comment: The virtualised Snow Leopard and the VM is Intel and not PPC

Comment: But Intel Snow Leopard can run PPC apps thanks to Rosetta - if it can be made to work in a VM.

Answer (score -3):

only way i know is to use boot camp but that takes a hell lot of work

Comment: You are using Bootcamp to run PowerPC applications? Can you share some details?